# Bypass native facebook app in android

Tags: android, facebook, app-id

I have an app with uses facebook login to authenticate, it works perfectly when facebook native app is NOT installed in the phone, but when facebook native app IS INSTALLED i can't get the token.

**I know is a "signature mismatch" problem** but i am NOT the owner of the facebook app id, so i can't do anything here.

I would like to make this app prompt user/pass login even when the native facebook app is installed, in resume i want to make an app behave like there wasn't a native Facebook app installed.

Is there any way to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: There is parameter to force web login for FB sdk

Comment: Please what is that parameter? I need enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Eugen Martynov who lead me in the right way i found my answer

```
//this is the facebook button
private LoginButton loginBtn;

//this goes in your implementation BEFORE everything you do
loginBtn.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```

And thats it, your app user is now forced to log via web, avoiding all potential "signature mismatch" problems :)

Comment: This is just workaround for your problem. Integration with native app gives a lot sweet things. For example user don't need to type login password in the each app

Comment: Yes but i am using the facebook application id of another application that i DO NOT own, i need to log in with that facebook application id in order to get the token and use that application credentials. Yes, it probably break every EULA out there but my app is getting great success in the play store and Mr. Google didn't seems to mind.

Comment: That is changing things